# Implementing GraphQL as a middleware in gRPC-based microservices using Go: How do I map GraphQL queries to the right endpoint calls?

Tags: go, graphql, grpc, middleware

For my project, I am trying to add graphQL as a middle layer between my golang grpc backend and my reactjs frontend. However, I am not understanding how to connect the graphQL queries to call the grpc endpoints if that makes sense? I don't understand how to connect the layers to call the right data or do data manipulation.

Right now, I have the graphQL type definitions and query for a login and signup endpoint in my grpc microservice. Written like this in a schema file:

```
type LoginResponse {
  success: Boolean!
  token: String
  uuid: String
}

type SignupResponse {
  success: Boolean!
  token: String
  uuid: String
}

type Query {
  # Fetches a user's login response
  login(email: String!, password: String!): LoginResponse

  # Registers a new user and returns the signup response
  signup(email: String!, password: String!): SignupResponse
}
```

My go microservice is defined kind of like this:

```
package auth

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "log"

{other imports}

    uuid "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type AuthServer struct {
    store ds.AuthDatastore
    authpb.UnimplementedAuthServiceServer
}

func NewAuthServer(dsn string) (*AuthServer, error) {
    store, err := ds.NewAuthDatastore(dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("can't connect to database")
    }

    return &AuthServer{store: store}, nil
}

// Login validates that the user has the correct credentials
func (s *AuthServer) Login(ctx context.Context, req *authpb.LoginRequest) (*authpb.LoginResponse, error) {

{do something here}

    log.Printf("Login Call: Login Successful!")
    return resp, nil
}

// Signup registers a new user in database and ensures they don't already exist
func (s *AuthServer) Signup(ctx context.Context, req *authpb.SignupRequest) (*authpb.SignupResponse, error) {

{do something here}

    log.Printf("Signup Call: Signup Successful!")
    return resp, nil
}
```

I don't understand how the graphQL query maps to the right endpoint call and have not implemented it correctly.